# How do I make bevel cuts to form a ring with 2x4s?

Tags: woodworking

I want to make a round wishing well. I have 12 2x4s 12" long. What angle of bevel do I need so they fit into a tight circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bevel on each side of the 2x4 would need to be 15˚.

Assuming the 2x4s are standard dimensions of 1.5" x 3.5" your twelve 2x4s will make a construction that is just over 13" across. You may want to evaluate if that is the size you want.

[image]

If you desired a construction that was a bit bigger you could use 24 2x4s with a 7.5˚ bevel. That would yield a unit that was about 26.5" across.

Answer (score 4):

15˚ (360 / 12 / 2) on each side of each 2x4.